# Connect session in PostgreSQL with SailsJS

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, connect

I have a personal project in SailsJS, Passport-Local and PostgreSQL. I managed to get connection and save users in PostgreSQL DB. But I have big problem with session storing. From what I know SailsJS is using Connect to get it done.

Previous working code for MongoDB:

```
connections: {
    prodMongodbServer: {
        adapter: 'sails-mongo',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        //user: '',
        //password: '',
        database: 'sails-auth'
    }
},

session: {
    adapter: 'mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    db: 'sails-auth',
    collection: 'sessions'
}
```

My (working) connection to PostgreSQL:

```
connections: {
    somePostgresqlServer: {
      adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      user: 'postgres',
      password: 'Password1',
      database: 'sails-auth'
    }
},
```

And the code I have problem with:

```
session: {
    adapter: 'connect-pg-simple',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'Password1',
    db: 'sails-auth'
}
```

I've installed [connect-pg-simple](https://github.com/voxpelli/node-connect-pg-simple), executed SQL code but when I am starting sails app I get an error:

```
$ sails lift

info: Starting app...

Init Express midleware
Failed to prune sessions: password authentication failed for user "myPcUser"
info:
info:                .-..-.
info:
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.11.3             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info:
```

I thought that it may be beetter to use [connect-pg](https://github.com/jebas/connect-pg), but it requires so many dependecy that I stayed with simple version. Anyone know what this problem is about? Im on windows so its weird that it have problem with my PC User...

Or maybe someone have some solution for using PostgreSQL for users, etc and Mongo for sessions. For what I've tested Passport doesnt allow to do that (user can sign up but can't sign in)

Comment: I am facing this exact same issue, did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: also still having an issue with this, specifically it seems to want to connect to connect-pg-simple as my operating system user not the user specified in session.js.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can fix this error open PostgreSQL client authentication configuration file:

`/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`

and change:

local   all all             trust

host    all 127.0.0.1/32    trust

Save and close the file. Restart Postgresql server:

service postgresql restart

Comment: on windows: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 1):

To make it work

1. Install the connect-pg-simple node module: $ npm install connect-pg-simple
2. In session.js define the adapter and connection string:

`adapter: 'connect-pg-simple',
  conString: 'postgres://user:pass@host:5432/dbname',`

3) run the SQL commands on file node_modules/connect-pg-simple/table.sql to create the table for sessions. :

`CREATE TABLE "session" (
  "sid" varchar NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "sess" json NOT NULL,
    "expire" timestamp(6) NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "session" ADD CONSTRAINT "session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("sid") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
CREATE INDEX "IDX_session_expire" ON "session" ("expire");`

Answer (score 0):

I used for that [sails-pg-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-pg-session).
The information about sessions must be stored in  config/session.js:

```
adapter: 'sails-pg-session',
database: 'dbname',
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'dbuser',
  password: 'dbpasswd',
  port: 5432
```

Hope it helps